# Can't view table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

When using phpmyadmin I can't display the table `wp_postmeta`.

No matter if I click on the table on the sidebar or do a manual query, phpmyadmin automatically adds `` inner join `wp_posts` onpost_id=`wp_posts`.id `` and returns the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join`wp_posts` onpost_id=`wp_posts`.id
>   LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

It only does this on this specific table.

How do I prevent phpmyadmin from doing this and where could it came from?

Comment: Is this article useful?  https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/clean-wp-commentmeta-wp-postmeta/

Comment: @ChrisFNZ Helped me to at least have a look inside the table again, not 100% solved but a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql is a php application and as every application may have some problems or bugs, which query you have tested to retrieve the data? this?

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
```

Maybe your wp_postmeta table is corrupted, you can try to fix it with phpmyadmin function, but before doing this be sure to do a **full database backup**

Here you can find where you can repair the table:
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/repair-optimize-database/

Comment: Yes that's the querry I used. I just did the repairing and optimizing but the problem is still present

Comment: Ok, maybe the problem isn't in that table but in other table like a missing foreign key (maybe relative to post_id in posts table) that infect this table, you now have a db dump try to repair all table: https://hosting.review/tips-tools/repair-wordpress-database/

Comment: I did serveral repairs now with different methods, all telling me everything works as intended. – At this point I think it's an error with phpmyadmin

Comment: mm, for strange problem you can try a strange solution... you can try to query with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM wp_postmeta` or change the table name (every potential cache not working anymore) and try the query, if with a new name the query work you can try to change prefix to all wordpress table: https://www.developerdrive.com/how-to-change-the-wordpress-database-prefix-to-improve-security/

Comment: That querry actually worked. The problem is still present, but I can use that as a workaround, thank you!

Comment: Good news, you can try to clear cache of entire db: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-status-and-maintenance.html

Comment: I can say from experience that PhpMyAdmin has lots of strange quirks. I would recommend updating / upgrading it to the lateat version. I moved to TOAD for MySQL which I use over an SSH tunnel and all the problems I had when I used PhpMyAdmin disappeared.

Comment: @red I think clearing the cache would help here, but `#1227 - Access denied;` ... I guess it's time to switch hosting.